# Getting 415 - Unsupported Media Type in Postman post method

Tags: rest, api, amazon-web-services, postman

I have using postman (https://www.getpostman.com/) for testing my APIs
APIs are in AWS ApiGateway and Lambda function (NodeJS)

(1) When first time I am sending post method request to server, it's giving proper response, I am not sending any post params for now.

**Here is request header-**

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →61
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Fri, 24 Mar 2017 09:09:13 GMT
Via →1.1 440f7503597ca64245c4258c03b08e0c.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id →t50_SeWgC3Qb2ZFtf4fksUTdi5viINCaAEj8MPTvhRbtMHu-LK1mwA==
X-Amzn-Trace-Id →Root=1-58d4e239-76404c1ab9912d010fac33a2
X-Cache →Miss from cloudfront
x-amzn-RequestId →8c8f9bd2-1071-11e7-9490-79b68cde95e0
```

**Here is response**

```
{
  "response": "false",
  "message": "Please enter a valid email !"
}
```

Its working fine when no post params send to request.

(2) And now when I am sending some params to request , 
    The request header changed and its removed one header prama
    **X-Amzn-Trace-Id**

**Here is request header-**

```
Connection →keep-alive
Content-Length →37
Content-Type →application/json
Date →Fri, 24 Mar 2017 09:02:52 GMT
Via →1.1 d6cd0a105a9b074288944d270dfa7321.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id →UZLUL1lYwAIrnwaa7kPVrPBx462sa7sV0x0WFQFGJ2OXVbrp9gaNYg==
X-Cache →Error from cloudfront
x-amzn-RequestId →a9c4116a-1070-11e7-b08c-c3cf73411cde
```

**Here is request body**

```
{
"userEmail":"rahul@gmail.com",
"userPasswod":"123456",
"userName":"rahul"
}
```

**Here is response**

```
{
  "message": "Unsupported Media Type"
}
```

After lot of R&D I have also added `content/Type- application/json` in header but still getting same response.

Please somebody help me to figure out this issue with postman.

Comment: does your API on server side supports the application/json content type? can you post the code which handle this request on server side?

Comment: Yes Its supports application/json content type.

I am working on AWS lambda function and api gateway

Answer (score 10):

I was having a similar experience using postman and aws.  I could get the appropriate response testing within AWS but when I tested within postman I'd get "Unsupported Media Type"  I solved it in postman by selecting the Body tab, then selecting the raw radio button, then selecting JSON(application/json) in the dropdown.  Finally I filled in the raw data similar to what my test data in AWS looked like.  It looked something like this:

[postman image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPyd8.png)

I hope that helps, good luck!

Comment: Yes I know that, Its working with raw data , 
But I need to know why its not working with form data.